# What is the best way to vary Javascript bundles per view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Some of my views require jQueryUI, some do not.

Rather than adding logic to my _Layout.cshtml Razor view, what is the best way to conditionally add certain bundles.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the `@section` directive.

In your `Layout.cshtml`:

```
<head>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("CustomScripts", false)
</head>
```

Then somewhere in your `View`:

```
@section CustomScripts
{
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery.ui")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery.templates")
}
```

This way even if you set `CustomScripts` later in your view, it will always appear in the `head` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the script link at the bottom of the views that need it?

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

Comment: Except the calls would be in the wrong place, outside the header or not at the bottom of the page.